# Connect to macOS based system over serial console?

Tags: mac, console

Does anyone know whether it is possible to connect to a macOS based system over a serial port to get a console?

This was possible over the XServe DB9 connector but I’m wondering if it can be done over a USB port on a modern Mac?

Comment: You can get a console by booting the mac into single user mode. Or you can access a device via SSH. Can you specify more clearly what you are trying to achieve on what device?

Comment: Sure, I'm essentially wondering if I can rely on a USB port for say, a mac mini to obtain shell access for management and maintenance. Much in the same way one would configure routers, switches, etc., over a dedicated console port.

Comment: I don't think you can. The only solution I can think of is connect to the same network and use ssh.